# Bbox set twice for requests

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I wanted to set a custom bbox for my map tiles, but the resulting request consists of two parameters:

[image]

The map wms service gives me an error  `Found multiple, inconsistent values for parameter BBOX`

How do I solve this?

This my code for the maps:

```
L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
            bbox: [9.6483, 47.5090, 12.1807, 49.1666],
        }).addTo(map);

        var wmsLayer = L.tileLayer.wms('https://maps.dwd.de/geoserver/wms?', {
            layers: 'dwd:FX-Produkt',
            format: 'image/png',
            transparent: true,
            version: '1.3.0',
            bbox: [9.6483, 47.5090, 12.1807, 49.1666],
        }).addTo(map);
```

My attempt was to display a part of a map, f.e. a region or a single state without loading other (unnecessary) tiles.

Comment: The question is: *why* are you setting a `bbox` at instantiation time? What's the purpose you're seeking from that?

Comment: @IvanSanchez My intention was to display only a specific area, in my case a regional state. The documentation I read suggested this, but if this approach is wrong or unfavorable please tell me :)

Comment: https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#gridlayer-bounds

Comment: This is an instance of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I suggest editing your question to add this background information and rephrasing everything.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there maybe an example for the GridLayer?

Comment: @IvanSanchez also I still do not understand, how the Grid Layer would prevent my wms ans osm map from loading out-of-bound data. Does leaflet offer an option to set a border where data-loading should be stopped?

Comment: That's exactly what the `bounds` option of `GridLayer` does. See e.g. https://plnkr.co/edit/se38NnkEibfpEPaL